# 3d cubical transition preloader

Tags: 3d, transition, preloader

[I've attached a link here for the video of 3D cubical transition effects](https://s3.envato.com/h264-video-previews/7e1a6e0b-1c43-47bd-89b4-f5d8f6af6ab5/19155655.mp4)

Is this possible to make the first effects from the video using JS or jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have a hard time getting it as nice as in the video, with the shades and so.

You could have a look at this to have a startingpoint: http://stanko.github.io/cube-3D-rotate-grid/

Comment: thanks, Jasper but This will not useful for me because I've to use that effects for the preloader.